# Setting custom info window for markers of google map with data from JSON android

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps

I am working on a project where there are marker pins shown on google map with latitiude and longitude retrieved from server.But i want to customize the info window in such a way that it contains title as well as price(Both fields are present in the JSON response).One way to do it would be to iterate through the list containing the data and check against the corresponding latitude of the marker pin(using marker.getLatitude()) , and then getting the corresponding title and price and then setting it in the below methods:

```
googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

            // Use default InfoWindow frame
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                return null;
            }
```

EDIT:THIS IS THE CODE WHICH I HAVE USED

```
for(int i=0;i<job_list.size();i++)
        {
            Job_data j=job_list.get(i);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(j.job_shop_name)
                    .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(j.job_shop_latitude),Double.parseDouble(j.job_shop_longitude))));



        }
```

How do i modify the above code to set details for the custom info window?
                // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
                @Override
                public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

```
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);

               //possibly iterate through the list containing the json data and then set it here 

                return v;

            }
        });
```

Is my approach right or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: What I do is set the marker title to the json content. And on infoContents parse that content and display it on the view

Comment: @PedroOliveira see edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of saving the title on the marker save the whole json text instead.

I presume your `j` is a job and your `job_list` contains all the jobs. You just need to save the JSON of the current object too. Something like `j.json_text`. You need to save the json on the object when you create it. Then change your marker title to the json string.

```
 googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(j.json_text)
                .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(j.job_shop_latitude), Double.parseDouble(j.job_shop_longitude))));
```

Then on your `getInfoWindow` you can do `new JSONObject object = arg0.getTitle()` and then you have your job (complete).

Another way is to concatenate the job title and the price. Something like:

`new MarkerOptions().title(j.job_shop_name + "@@@" + j.job_shop_price)`

And then on `getInfoWindow` split the marker title and you have your price:

```
String[] contents = arg0.getTitle().split("@@@");
String title = contents[0];
String price = contents[1];
```

Comment: Can i use j.toString() to set the title in the title of the marker

Comment: If your Job object doesn't have `toString()` implemented then you can't. Because even if you can transform it into a string how are you supposed to retrieve it from a string? There is no `fromString()`

Comment: .The issue is that i have parsed the json string as a whole and cant retrieve it for a particular job.job_data is an arraylist of type Job_data which is a class with many fields.How am i suppose to get the specific json object from that?But i have the whole json string saved as result.Can i use that?

Comment: Then use the second solution. Concatenate your string and split it on the other part. It's easier than you think :)

Comment: is it arg0.split("@@@") or arg0.title.split("@@@")?

Comment: `arg0.getTitle().split("@@@")` Sorry. I will edit the solution